# `AdapterNotSpecified` database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

My database is a MySQL running on `localhost`. The `mysql2` gem installed without errors.  I never managed to connect, regardless of which login I used.

The root password contains a `#` which is the comment character in Sublime Text 2 editor so I think it might not be passing my password correctly.

I tried using double- and single quotes, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I also tried creating a new user and giving that user privileges on the command line.

I have read a lot of similiar posts here but haven't found solution yet.

Below is a stack trace of the error:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\siteone\simple_cms>rake db:schema:dump --trace
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'mysql2' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "adapter", "encoding", "pool", "username", "password", "host", "development", "database", "socket"]
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol
_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:231:in `resolve_string_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:213:in `resolve_connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:151:in `block in resolve_all'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `each'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:46:in `configurations='
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `<class:MySQLDatabaseTasks>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:3:in `<module:Tasks>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:50:in `<module:DatabaseTasks>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:37:in `<module:Tasks>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in`<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:dump => db:load_config

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\siteone\simple_cms>
```

---

I edited `database.yml` and now the error has changed slightly.

```
default: 
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: simple_cms
password: mypass
host: localhost

development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
database: simple_cms_development
username: simple_cms
password: 
host: localhost
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

---

And finally, my `connection_specification.rb` file, where I believe the issue lies.

```
require 'uri'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/filters'

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class ConnectionSpecification #:nodoc:
      attr_reader :config, :adapter_method

      def initialize(config, adapter_method)
        @config, @adapter_method = config, adapter_method
      end

      def initialize_dup(original)
        @config = original.config.dup
      end

      # Expands a connection string into a hash.
      class ConnectionUrlResolver # :nodoc:

        # == Example
        #
        #   url = "postgresql://foo:bar@localhost:9000/foo_test?pool=5&timeout=3000"
        #   ConnectionUrlResolver.new(url).to_hash
        #   # => {
        #     "adapter"  => "postgresql",
        #     "host"     => "localhost",
        #     "port"     => 9000,
        #     "database" => "foo_test",
        #     "username" => "foo",
        #     "password" => "bar",
        #     "pool"     => "5",
        #     "timeout"  => "3000"
        #   }
        def initialize(url)
          raise "Database URL cannot be empty" if url.blank?
          @uri     = uri_parser.parse(url)
          @adapter = @uri.scheme.tr('-', '_')
          @adapter = "postgresql" if @adapter == "postgres"

          if @uri.opaque
            @uri.opaque, @query = @uri.opaque.split('?', 2)
          else
            @query = @uri.query
          end
        end

        # Converts the given URL to a full connection hash.
        def to_hash
          config = raw_config.reject { |_,value| value.blank? }
          config.map { |key,value| config[key] = uri_parser.unescape(value) if value.is_a? String }
          config
        end

        private

        def uri
          @uri
        end

        def uri_parser
          @uri_parser ||= URI::Parser.new
        end

        # Converts the query parameters of the URI into a hash.
        #
        #   "localhost?pool=5&reaping_frequency=2"
        #   # => { "pool" => "5", "reaping_frequency" => "2" }
        #
        # returns empty hash if no query present.
        #
        #   "localhost"
        #   # => {}
        def query_hash
          Hash[(@query || '').split("&").map { |pair| pair.split("=") }]
        end

        def raw_config
          if uri.opaque
            query_hash.merge({
              "adapter"  => @adapter,
              "database" => uri.opaque })
          else
            query_hash.merge({
              "adapter"  => @adapter,
              "username" => uri.user,
              "password" => uri.password,
              "port"     => uri.port,
              "database" => database_from_path,
              "host"     => uri.hostname })
          end
        end

        # Returns name of the database.
        def database_from_path
          if @adapter == 'sqlite3'
            # 'sqlite3:/foo' is absolute, because that makes sense. The
            # corresponding relative version, 'sqlite3:foo', is handled
            # elsewhere, as an "opaque".

            uri.path
          else
            # Only SQLite uses a filename as the "database" name; for
            # anything else, a leading slash would be silly.

            uri.path.sub(%r{^/}, "")
          end
        end
      end

      ##
      # Builds a ConnectionSpecification from user input.
      class Resolver # :nodoc:
        attr_reader :configurations

        # Accepts a hash two layers deep, keys on the first layer represent
        # environments such as "production". Keys must be strings.
        def initialize(configurations)
          @configurations = configurations
        end

        # Returns a hash with database connection information.
        #
        # == Examples
        #
        # Full hash Configuration.
        #
        #   configurations = { "production" => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "sqlite3" } }
        #   Resolver.new(configurations).resolve(:production)
        #   # => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "sqlite3"}
        #
        # Initialized with URL configuration strings.
        #
        #   configurations = { "production" => "postgresql://localhost/foo" }
        #   Resolver.new(configurations).resolve(:production)
        #   # => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "postgresql" }
        #
        def resolve(config)
          if config
            resolve_connection config
          elsif env = ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling::RAILS_ENV.call
            resolve_symbol_connection env.to_sym
          else
            raise AdapterNotSpecified
          end
        end

        # Expands each key in @configurations hash into fully resolved hash
        def resolve_all
          config = configurations.dup
          config.each do |key, value|
            config[key] = resolve(value) if value
          end
          config
        end

        # Returns an instance of ConnectionSpecification for a given adapter.
        # Accepts a hash one layer deep that contains all connection information.
        #
        # == Example
        #
        #   config = { "production" => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "sqlite3" } }
        #   spec = Resolver.new(config).spec(:production)
        #   spec.adapter_method
        #   # => "sqlite3_connection"
        #   spec.config
        #   # => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "sqlite3" }
        #
        def spec(config)
          spec = resolve(config).symbolize_keys

          raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "database configuration does not specify adapter") unless spec.key?(:adapter)

          path_to_adapter = "active_record/connection_adapters/#{spec[:adapter]}_adapter"
          begin
            require path_to_adapter
          rescue Gem::LoadError => e
            raise Gem::LoadError, "Specified '#{spec[:adapter]}' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem '#{e.name}'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)."
          rescue LoadError => e
            raise LoadError, "Could not load '#{path_to_adapter}'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.", e.backtrace
          end

          adapter_method = "#{spec[:adapter]}_connection"
          ConnectionSpecification.new(spec, adapter_method)
        end

        private

        # Returns fully resolved connection, accepts hash, string or symbol.
        # Always returns a hash.
        #
        # == Examples
        #
        # Symbol representing current environment.
        #
        #   Resolver.new("production" => {}).resolve_connection(:production)
        #   # => {}
        #
        # One layer deep hash of connection values.
        #
        #   Resolver.new({}).resolve_connection("adapter" => "sqlite3")
        #   # => { "adapter" => "sqlite3" }
        #
        # Connection URL.
        #
        #   Resolver.new({}).resolve_connection("postgresql://localhost/foo")
        #   # => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "postgresql" }
        #
        def resolve_connection(spec)
          case spec
          when Symbol
            resolve_symbol_connection spec
          when String
            resolve_string_connection spec
          when Hash
            resolve_hash_connection spec
          end
        end

        def resolve_string_connection(spec)
          # Rails has historically accepted a string to mean either
          # an environment key or a URL spec, so we have deprecated
          # this ambiguous behaviour and in the future this function
          # can be removed in favor of resolve_url_connection.
          if configurations.key?(spec) || spec !~ /:/
            ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(<<-MSG.squish)
              Passing a string to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection for a
              configuration lookup is deprecated, please pass a symbol
              (#{spec.to_sym.inspect}) instead.
            MSG

            resolve_symbol_connection(spec)
          else
            resolve_url_connection(spec)
          end
        end

        # Takes the environment such as +:production+ or +:development+.
        # This requires that the @configurations was initialized with a key that
        # matches.
        #
        #   Resolver.new("production" => {}).resolve_symbol_connection(:production)
        #   # => {}
        #
        def resolve_symbol_connection(spec)
          if config = configurations[spec.to_s]
            resolve_connection(config)
          else
            raise(AdapterNotSpecified, "'#{spec}' database is not configured. Available: #{configurations.keys.inspect}")
          end
        end

        # Accepts a hash. Expands the "url" key that contains a
        # URL database connection to a full connection
        # hash and merges with the rest of the hash.
        # Connection details inside of the "url" key win any merge conflicts
        def resolve_hash_connection(spec)
          if spec["url"] && spec["url"] !~ /^jdbc:/
            connection_hash = resolve_url_connection(spec.delete("url"))
            spec.merge!(connection_hash)
          end
          spec
        end

        # Takes a connection URL.
        #
        #   Resolver.new({}).resolve_url_connection("postgresql://localhost/foo")
        #   # => { "host" => "localhost", "database" => "foo", "adapter" => "postgresql" }
        #
        def resolve_url_connection(url)
          ConnectionUrlResolver.new(url).to_hash
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: probably problem with line 12 of database.yml - I suggest you add it to your question. You can trim that stack trace in the interest of improving readability (or at least format it)

Comment: Actually I modified the database.yml file now it is not getting the same error but it is still not working.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `database` option for the `default` configuration. Try adding `database: <your_database_name>`

Comment: tried that but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is an indentation problem in your database.yml and you haven't specified the database name in your default connection. It should look like this:

```
default: 
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5
    database: database_name
    username: simple_cms
    password: mypass
    host: localhost

development:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    pool: 5
    database: simple_cms_development
    username: simple_cms
    password: 
    host: localhost
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is because of mysql password try changing the mysql password

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password 'newpassword'
```

Comment: removed the password completely for the user account still not working, I think the problem is in the connection_specification.rb file

Comment: I am able to connect with a test script via ruby so the issue is somewhere in the configuration files, I just don't understand the underlying config well enough to fix it, which is a shame the tutorial I am following does not have any troubleshooting assistance. I am able to connect via this file with these settings 'code' require 'mysql2'
client=Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: 'hiddenforsecurityreasons')
sql='show databases'
result=client.query(sql)
result.each do |row|
 puts row['Database']
end
'code'

Answer (score 0):

I wound up removing mysql2 and using an older version of it, manual download of the connector mysql-connect-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32 works, I also added the following to bundle config, bundle build mysql2 --with-mysql-dir=c:\%pathtosqlconnectorhere%, and I regenerated the application code, now rails can create the db, and I can login to it successfully without error.